How to get the parameter only from URL during window event
When the browser forward or back button is pushed, I use the code below to detect a URL parameter change. Note, the page never really changes, only the parameter that I add using a HTML data attribute.
            window.navigation.addEventListener("navigate", (event) => {
                var changedURL = event.destination.url;
                console.log(changedURL);

In the console log, I get the below.
practice.php?url=homepage:58 http://localhost/practice.php?url=page3

I want to get only the very end of the result, i.e., "?=page3". I want to save that parameter only in a variable, and nothing before it.

Something like (?<=.php?)\S+$ would get everything after the second .php?

I ended up finding this solution.
var changedURL = event.destination.url;
changedURL = changedURL.substring(changedURL.indexOf("?"));

